# Why do matching algorithms use point estimates rather than intervals?

Tags: confidence-interval, algorithms, uncertainty, matching, point-estimation

I'm developing a matching algorithm, and I am wondering why websites choose using point estimates, e.g. "You match 60% with person X".

Given that there will be most likely be missing data, rather than for instance penalizing error scores for answers we are not sure of, why wouldn't we present an interval, e.g. "You match between 70-80% with person X".

Perhaps this would even be a good incentive for people to fill in more information.

Does anyone know what is most likely the main reasons point estimates are shown and not intervals?

Comment: Non-statisticians generally want a single number and don't care about confidence intervals, often because it is easier to make comparisons (even when comparisons make no sense).

Comment: @MarcClaesen I also think that's the main reason. Would it be a bad assumption that people would try to diminish the uncertainty by filling in their profile more completely when faced with a (large) interval?

Comment: In my experience, novices are often underwhelmed by the whoa-factor of conclusions based on statistical validity (they expect much more outrageous results). I fear that a considerable amount of people would not (care to) understand where a large interval comes from and instead lose interest in the service because it seems unable to give detailed information. Keep it simple is the best approach for general public applications (even if that implies giving incomplete information based on questionable assumptions within ethical limits). Numbers are hot, proper interpretations/inference are not.